# How to iterate over each value stored in a List<Long>?

Tags: android, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, arraylist

I have a function whose parameter is `List<Long> l`.

In the function there is a `if` statement for which I have to iterate over each value stored in the `List<Long> l`.

I'm trying to do this:

```
    public void myFunction(final List<Long> l) {

        final int size = l.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
           if (l.get(i) <= 900) {
              ...       
           Log.d("resultL", String.valueOf(l.get(i)));
           } else {
           }
        }

    }
```

here `resultL` logged only `-64338`

the values stored in the `List<Long> l` are `[-64338, -15512, -15224, 8344]`, but what is happening is that the `if` statement is using only `-64338` and doing the logic instead of using all the 4 values.

**UPDATE 1**:

using @KushPatel's answer, `resultL` printed out:

```
D/resultL: -64338
D/resultL: -15512
D/resultL: -15224
D/resultL: -64338
D/resultL: -15512
D/resultL: -15224
D/resultL: -64338
D/resultL: -15512
D/resultL: -15224
D/resultL: -64338
D/resultL: -15512
D/resultL: -15224
```

**Why** is this happening?

**How to** iterate over all the 4 values stored here and not just one?

Please help with this issue.

Comment: do you have any `return` or `break` inside your `if` statement?

Comment: you need to provide at least some logic of how you use the iterating value within the `if` block to determine the issue here

Comment: @koceeng no, there is no `return` or `break`.

Comment: Post your `if` statement implementation

Comment: @koperko have a look at edited code

Comment: Note that if this isn't an ArrayList, indexed lookups are relatively expensive.

Comment: of course it logs only one value if you put it inside your loop

Comment: @koceeng "Of course it only does something once if it's inside a loop" doesn't really make sense-it's in a loop that iterates over a list with more than one element.

Comment: No, I mean the `Log.d` will only show one at a time. And I comment that just to make sure @HammadNasir doesn't miss the other log entry

Comment: do you have set break point before the loop and check the size of the list, try to send Arrays.asList(new Long[]{-64338l, -15512l, -15224l, 8344l})   as parameter, i have try it with same your code and it work fine

Comment: @HammadNasir correct me if I'm wrong. Do you want to do the logic on `-64338, -15512, -15224` and not on `8344`? (filter value less than 900)?

Comment: @koceeng yes... only on the values less than `900`.

Comment: check my answer

Comment: why didn't you try to debug "step-by-step" your simple loop? your list has just four elements, you would know the reason after just couple of clicks...

Comment: @pskink I am unable to understand this... please tell me more briefly

Comment: If you're getting the same loop executed over and over then  you're calling it over and over. There's more going on here than what you're showing.

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html#breakPoints

Comment: @DaveNewton this is basically what I'm trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41389675/6144372

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want to do something after you get all values less than 900 right. Then you should first place them inside another `List`

```
public void myFunction(final List<Long> l) {

    final int size = l.size();
    List<Long> results = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
       if (l.get(i) <= 900) {
           results.add(l.get(i));
       } else {
           ...
       }
    }

    // do your thing with results list
}
```

I think there are lot of ways to do this, but this is simple and easy to understand.

Comment: no... I think I have somehow failed to explain my problem here, but here I have explained it much clearly: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41389675/6144372 Please help.

Comment: I am not familiar with FastAdapter, so I think others may help you. Sorry

Comment: but you can help me with some common logic that should be used here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you should perform some operation if all of your elements are less or equals than 900. Right? 
Try smth like this:

```
boolean isDataValid = true;
for(Long num : l){
     if (num  > 900){
          isDataValid = false;
     }
}

if(isDataValid){

}else{

}
```

Comment: isn't this similar to what @KushPatel has answered: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41380770/6144372 ?

Comment: Isn't the `m` should be `num` in this?

Answer (score 0):

Several problems:

1) You are using [Long](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) to represent negative numbers

> which has a minimum value of 0 and a maximum value of 264-1. Use this data type when you need a range of values wider than those provided by int.

2) You are checking if a number is less then 900

> if (l.get(i) <= 900)

Negative Long numbers will overflow and become positive numbers, Java (like most computer architectures these days) uses something called [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), so some of your negetive numbers become numbers that are bigger then 900 and they won't be printed on screen.

**Solution**

1) Use an [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) instead of a Long

```
public void myFunction(final List<Integer> l) {

final int size = l.size();
List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
   if (l.get(i) <= 900) {
       results.add(l.get(i));
   } else {
       ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public void myFunction(final List<Long> l) {
    for (Long m:l){
       if (m <= 900) {
          ...       
       } else {
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: it is highly improbable that this will solve anything as it is just another syntax to the same logic

Comment: Unrelated, but size is no longer necessary.