# Unable to write an algorithm for filtering out items in a RecyclerView based on a long saved with each item

Tags: java, android, algorithm, android-recyclerview, fastadapter

I have several items in a `RecyclerView` and each item has a `long` value saved with it. I'm using [FastAdapter](https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter) as the adapter for my `RecyclerView`.

Suppose there are 7 items in the `RecyclerView` with the long values: `11122`, `12321`, `-98811`, `8870`, `-88009`, `3398`, and `-22113`.

So, **what I want to** do is, I want to filter the items based on the above given long values using this logic:

```
if (l <= 1000) {
  // show items with long value <=1000
} else if (l > 1000) {
  // show items with long value >1000
}
```

I tried various things, but nothing worked out.

**UPDATE 1**: Items here are a sort of different data stored in `CardView` and then shown in `RecyclerView`. Each card contains different data, one of which are the above given `long` values. I want to filter the data based on these `long` values stored in each card based on the logic given above.

Please help me with this issue and suggest some algorithm or code with which I can achieve this.

Comment: With the amount of detail given, this calls for a reformulation of the fine manuals. It might prove more constructive to actually _show_ what you tried _and_ describe what you observed and in how far this fell short of being sufficient.

Comment: Alright, just looked through your edit. Now, if I'm am correct there are several cards inside `RecyclerView`, and you want to display all the cards, but only the information that is displayed inside the card must be filtered according to the long value. Am I right?

Comment: @abhi no.. I want to display only those cards in which the `long` value stored is either `<=1000` or `>1000` respectively as chose by the user.

Comment: have you to implement `Filterable`? which is best solution and also it's dynamic solution.

Comment: @Moinkhan I tried but I'm unable to create a logic! It isn't working.. :/

Answer (score 6):

With the amount of information given I can only suppose `l` is a foreign selector value which controls the items to be displayed inside the `RecyclerView`. Comment below if this is not the case, I will try to correct my answer.

I recommend implementing a custom `ViewAdapter`, sending in the list of items and the selector variable `l` using respective methods:

```
public class ItemsAdapter extends 
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemsAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {

    private List<Long> mItemList;
    private List<Long> mDisplayItems;
    private boolean mAboveThousand = true;

    public void setItemList(List<Long> list) {
        mItemList = list;
        updateDisplayItems();
    }

    public void setSelectionType(boolean aboveThousand) {
        mAboveThousand = aboveThousand;
        updateDisplayItems();
    }

    private updateDisplayItems() {
        mDisplayItems.clear();

        for(Long item: mItemList) {
            if(/*check your contition*/) {
                mDisplayItems.add(item);
            }
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged(); //important
    }

    ...
    // Rest of implementation
}
```

Also, I have never used FastAdapter, but I suppose there must be some methods to override if you extend its class.

### Update

Since, you are facing problems understanding the basics of using a `ViewAdapter`, I would recommend learning and implementing a custom `ViewAdapter` before using any library. [Here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview)'s a extensive tutorial for how to implement `ViewAdapter` for RecyclerView.

Now, after you have implemented the ViewAdapter you can use my piece of code to filter out cards. Basically, what the code is doing is saving a list of all the required data inside `mItemList`, while `mDisplayList` is a list storing the items to be displayed, which is updated every-time `mAboveThousand`, which stores the user preference of above or below 1000, is set. Now this `mDisplayList` must be used to inflate data inside the RecyclerView.

Comment: `l` is the following: `11122`, `12321`, `-98811`, `8870`, `-88009`, `3398`, and `-22113`. Saved with the items of `RecyclerView` respectively.

Comment: @HammadNasir I cannot understand how exactly do you want to filter the "items", also what exactly do you mean by items. Can you please clarify with an example?

Comment: thanks for responding, please checkout the edited question (the part written in **UPDATE 1**).

Comment: abhi's answer here works just as well. Though the "rest of the implementation" involves the dynamic different viewholders based on the type. Then it doesn't matter what is in the mDisplayItems list because even if you fed it every element it would just put them into their respective datatype accordingly.

Comment: Maybe this answer can solve my issue, but the problem is that I'm having difficulty in using this answer as I'm unable to understand how and where to use this! Please help me get this all clear. :|

Comment: @abhi here's what I tried to do using FastAdapter: https://gist.github.com/HammadNasir/0152e9513be1059dddb24b12072b74bc but it didn't worked!

Comment: @abhi please do not leave this yet.. WHAT SHOULD I DO? Should I just start all over and stop the use of `FastAdapter` here?

Comment: @HammadNasir Sorry for delay, actually my machine is broken and is out for repair, I cannot really help you with FastAdapter without trying it out. So I would suggest you to drop FastAdapter for now and switch to the normal one.

Answer (score 4):

Even your very basic code there would work. You can count the number of items in that range and return the number in that range. I suggest you try to do this without FastAdapter because the core concept of parsing the data based on a filter value is rightly perfectly solid. You can iterate the loop and count them, and you can iterate the loop and return the nth item.

Comment: A bit of code according to your answer would really be very helpful.

Comment: You can setup something to filter entries in the adapter, even what you have there should work. My best suggestion to you is go from the most basic elements that should obviously work to more complex element. And lose FastAdapter for the time being until you get the other bits to work.

Comment: I'm unable to understand where to use Abhi's answer and also what you are saying as I'm not that much good android developer yet. Please help from the very basic like what and how should I do?

Comment: You write a standardish RecyclerAdapter and just filter the data that backs it according to whatever standard.

Answer (score 4):

If you do want to keep using FastAdapter, it has a built-in filter functionality (see point number 5 in the [README of the project](https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter). Note that the `filter` method should be called **after** `withFilterPredicate` and not before as shown there).

EDIT - after you pointed out that I misunderstood you before - here is my updated proposed instructions:

You need to resolve the logics of which set you want to display (using the checkboxes in the dialog you mentioned in the comment) and pass that information onto the filter, for example:

```
boolean displayUnderThreshold = //put the logic here - true if you want <1000
fastAdapter.filter(Boolean.toString(displayUnderThreshold));
```

And where you set the adapter (before the above line is called) have:

```
final long threshold = 1000;
fastAdapter.withFilterPredicate(new IItemAdapter.Predicate<GRModeClass>() {
    @Override
    public boolean filter(GRModeClass item, CharSequence constraint) {
        boolean displayUnderThreshold = new Boolean(constraint.toString());
        return (displayUnderThreshold ^ (item.l<threshold)); //false to remove from list
    }
});
```

---

#### Old answer

From when I thought you wanted to filter the items according to their `ms` long values, using an external `l` long indicator:

In your code, assuming your app does get to the `if` you mentioned in the question when it should - remove the `fastItemAdapter.clear();` and instead of the `for` loop with the `if` inside it write

```
fastItemAdapter.filter(Long.toString(l));
```

and somewhere **before** that, preferably where you set the adapter (most likely in the `onCreate` of `MainActivity`) add the following:

```
final long threshold = 1000;
fastAdapter.withFilterPredicate(new IItemAdapter.Predicate<GRModeClass>() {
    @Override
    public boolean filter(GRModeClass item, CharSequence constraint) {
        long indicator = new Long(constraint.toString());
        return (item.ms<threshold && indicator>=threshold) || (item.ms>=threshold && indicator<threshold) ;
    }
});
```

(Assuming here that `GRModeClass` is your items' class and that the `long ms` is the long you referred to that should determine whether the )

Comment: `l` is a `List<Long>` and can't be written as `fastItemAdapter.filter(Long.toString(l));` :/

Comment: So I probably didn't understand you correctly. I thought `l` is another single value, taken from somewhere else and should determine if we are to display all the cards that have `ms` value that is less than 1000 or those that have an `ms` value larger or equal to 1000. Am I wrong? If so - please reply here AND update your question.

Comment: I have clearly mentioned in the question that `l` is these values `11122, 12321, -98811, 8870, -88009, 3398, and -22113`. see both files here: https://gist.github.com/HammadNasir/0152e9513be1059dddb24b12072b74bc you ll get what I mean.

Comment: What is the boolean variable that determines if you want to show the cards with `l<1000` or those with `l>=1000`?

Comment: there isn't any boolean value. As you can see in the link I provided that there is a dialog which shown 2 `CheckBox` and then the user chose which cards to see.

Comment: I don't want to mess around with all your code. I am trying to answer the specific question you asked. I don't want to get into the inner logic of when you want to display each set of cards. Resolve the condition yourself and then use the answer I just updated to the way I understand your question now (each item has an `l` value that should determine if it's displayed or not based on some condition - something about the dialog and the checkboxes - I'll leave these details to you).

Answer (score 3):

I guess your class is like

```
public Class ListItem {
    // .. Some other attributes
    public long l;
}
```

Now I hope you've some function which is called when you're putting a filter in your `RecyclerView`. Let the function name is `toggleFilter`.

```
public void toggleFilter(long l) {
    if(l <= 1000) {
        fastAdapter.withFilterPredicate(new IItemAdapter.Predicate<Item>() {
            @Override
            public boolean filter(ListItem item, CharSequence constraint) {
                if(item.l <= 1000) return true;
                else return false; 
            }
        });

    } else if (l > 1000) {
        fastAdapter.withFilterPredicate(new IItemAdapter.Predicate<Item>() {
            @Override
            public boolean filter(ListItem item, CharSequence constraint) {
                if(item.l > 1000) return true;
                else return false; 
            }
        });
    }

    // Finally call notifyDataSetChanged        
    fastAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: isn't there any need to write this line somewhere: `fastItemAdapter.filter(conditions);`?

Comment: Nope. I guess so. Did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter while fetching from firebase.

l <= 1000

```
firebaseDatabase.child(key).orderByChild("long_value_key_in_firebase").endAt(1000);
```

l > 1000

```
firebaseDatabase.child(key).orderByChild("long_value_key_in_firebase").startAt(1000);
```